# Save Word Doc as contents of a certain Cell

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I am trying to set the name of my Word document as the contents of whats in the highlighted cell, given by code;  `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2)`

[image]

I have to do this for 200+ documents and the name will be in the same spot for all the documents.

This macro selects the desired cell and copies it

```
  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Select
  Selection.Copy
```

And this one saves the word document as a pdf with the clipboard contents as its name.

```
Sub rename()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileName As String


'set pathname accordingly
strPath = "enter path"

'create the Filename with your selection in Document
strFileName = Trim(Selection.Text) & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:= _
        strPath & strFileName _
        , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False

End Sub
```

The issue is that the second Macro does not work when I select the entire cell

[image]

[image]

Only when I select specific text, like below

[image]

Any solutions for this?

Many thanks again

Comment: Just being picky, but it would be helpful it you could explain the error as part of your question instead of making us find it in an unlabeled link.  It looks like the problem is the way you grab the file name.  You don't want to copy the cell, you want to copy the text in the cell.  FWIW, I wouldn't even copy it, I would just assign it directly to a variable.  Check out how to grab the cell text here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-tables

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
strFileName = Trim(Selection.Text) & ".pdf"
```

With this...

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,2).Range
    strFileName=ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=.Start, End:=.End-1) & ".pdf"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Word last character in a cell is always a special character with ASCII code 7 which mark the end of cell. You need to remove this character before using. There might be several way of doing it. You may replace this character as follows:

```
strFileName = Replace(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, Chr(7), "") & ".pdf"
```

Or, you may exclude it as follows:

```
charCount = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Characters.Count
strFileName = Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, charCount - 1)
```